# <asp:ListView DeleteMethod > not updating UI

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I an building a webforms page and making a lot of progress with web searches and help from the Stack Overflow community, but I have hit another snag that is likely due to my own inexperience.

Here is my ListView opening tag:

```
                <asp:ListView ID="lvLeadershipPositions"
                DataKeyNames="ID"
                InsertItemPosition="LastItem"
                runat="server" 
                ItemType="BusinessLogic.Alumni.Outreach.ServicePosition"
                SelectMethod="lvLeadershipPositions_GetData"
                InsertMethod="lvLeadershipPositions_InsertItem"
                UpdateMethod="lvLeadershipPositions_UpdateItem"
                DeleteMethod="lvLeadershipPositions_DeleteItem">
```

and here is the code behind for the `SelectMethod`, `InsertMethod`, `UpdateMethod` and `DeleteMethod`:

```
    public IEnumerable<ServicePosition> lvLeadershipPositions_GetData()
    {
        if (alumn == null)
        {
            alumn = new Alumn();
        }

        return alumn.LeadershipRoles;
    }

    public void lvLeadershipPositions_InsertItem()
    {
        var item = new BusinessLogic.Alumni.Outreach.ServicePosition();
        TryUpdateModel(item);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Save changes here
            item.ID = alumn.LeadershipRoles.Count;
            alumn.LeadershipRoles.Add(item);
        }
    }

    // The id parameter name should match the DataKeyNames value set on the control
    public void lvLeadershipPositions_UpdateItem(int id)
    {
        ServicePosition item = alumn.LeadershipRoles.Find(x => x.ID == id);
        // Load the item here, e.g. item = MyDataLayer.Find(id);
        if (item == null)
        {
            // The item wasn't found
            ModelState.AddModelError("", String.Format("Item with id {0} was not found", id));
            return;
        }
        TryUpdateModel(item);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Save changes here, e.g. MyDataLayer.SaveChanges();

        }
    }

    // The id parameter name should match the DataKeyNames value set on the control
    public void lvLeadershipPositions_DeleteItem(int id)
    {
        int count = alumn.LeadershipRoles.Count(x => x.ID == id);
        if (count == 1)
        {
            int removeID = alumn.LeadershipRoles.Where(x => x.ID == id).First().ID;
            alumn.LeadershipRoles.RemoveAt(removeID);
            return;
        }
        else if (count == 0)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", String.Format("Item with id {0} was not found", id));
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", String.Format("More than one Item with id {0} was found", id));
        }
    }
```

The first three methods all do exactly what I expect. For example, when clicking the update button on my page, the `lvLeadershipPositions_UpdateItem` method is called, and then the `lvLeadershipPositions_GetData` method is called.

And when I click the delete button `lvLeadershipPositions_DeleteItem` is called but `lvLeadershipPositions_GetData` is never called, so the page does not update to reflect my deletion.

What have I left out?

Comment: maybe it's missing the TryUpdateModel(item); in delete method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have removed the item from the data source but you haven't rebound the list view.

Force a rebind with **lvLeadershipPositions.DataBind()** or call your method TryUpdateModel(item) where maybe there is the DataBind call.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer I'll try that tomorrow morning.  I had tried rebinding data with `lvLeadershipPositions.DataSource` and the `.DataBind` but I had not tried adding TryUpdateModel, so I'll give that a try in the morning and update this post accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I had to leave out the `.DataSource()` line, add in the `.DataBind()` line and leave out the `TryUpdateModel(Item)` call. But I got it working!!!